# What does "console.log(phi(tableFor("peanut teeth", JOURNAL)))" do?

Tags: javascript, function, object

As I was reading through eloquent JavaScript, I came across the following example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < JOURNAL.length; i++) { 
        var entry = JOURNAL[i];
        if (hasEvent("peanuts", entry) &&
            !hasEvent("brushed teeth", entry)) 
            entry.events.push("peanut teeth");
   }

console.log(phi(tableFor("peanut teeth", JOURNAL))); 
// → 1
```

I keep trying to figure out whether the example is logging into the console the result of function phi whose parameters is the function tableFor, whose parameters are peanut teeth and JOURNAL.

So what I mainly do not understand is what is being logged into the console.

Any help is be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Find the definition of `tableFor()` and `phi()` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `console.log` prints the results of `phi()` after supplying it with the results you got from `tableFor("peanut teeth", JOURNAL)`

An easier way to look at this is:

```
var tableForResult = tableFor("peanut teeth", JOURNAL);
var phiResult = phi(tableForResult);
console.log(phiResult);
```

Comment: Ok so it kind of starts from the inside and bubbles out to the out most function!

Comment: Thank you very much! Great way to explain!